# Computer doesn't get further than motherboard screen after installing new ram?

Tags: windows-7, memory, graphics-card, ssd, motherboard

I just go new Kingston Hyper Beast DDR3 8x2GB kit in the door, but when I install them into my board, either my monitor doesn't react at all, or I get the motherboard screen which causes a restart and then repeat.

I tried:

- Inserting the ram and checked for the click sound.
- Tried 1 of them at a time, same result.
- Checking for damages, but when I insert the old RAM sticks it works as usual.
- Getting into BIOs to check for booting options, but it doesn't react (My keyboard is properly attached, and it works with some of
  the other options).

Any ideas? 
Specs:

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU 3,20GHz
- AMD Radeon Sapphire HD 7870 graphics card
- Gigabyte P55-USB3 motherboard
- Samsung SSD 840 EVO 120GB
- WDC WD5000AAKS-00V1A0 500GB

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you have are the [HyperX Beast 16GB (2 x 8GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 2400 (PC3 19200) Desktop Memory Model KHX24C11T3K2/16X](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820104374)  then what you have is faster then what your motherboard will support.  As you can see from the diagram your motherboard only supports 2200/1333/1066/800 Mhz DDR memory modules.

You also need to make sure your using 1.5V DDR3 DIMMs instead of 1.65V  DDR3 DIMMs like the HyperX Best modules.  Of course there are different versions of the HyperX Beast productline.    **I am going off the first result I located.**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So eiter new motherboard or another kind of memory!

Comment: Verify I found the correct kit.  There are 1.5v versions of the kit in question.  You were not specific with the details.

Comment: Mine is 1.65V :)

Comment: You write "what you have is faster then what your motherboard will support. As you can see from the diagram your motherboard only supports 2200/1333/1066/800 Mhz DDR memory modules."  <--- I think i'm right when I say that  RAM above that speed will still run but at the speed the Motherboard can handle.   To suggest that a motherboard only supports a particular speed of module is very inaccurate.